# Error in performing ajax post data and echoing those data on the console log

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

i was asked to perform ajax post data to the php script which will include the another script which perform sql connection to the database and get all data and convert data to json format. then the json data will be shown on the console. also i also was asked to modify the ajax to post the values such as name and the religion such as abdullah and muslim respectively.. I want to perform coding on the passwrapper to get and show data on the console.log..
in ajax.html

```
   <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Cesium-1.34/ThirdParty/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<div id="resulte"</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
showData();
function showData()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "passwrapper.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            lastName: 'Abdullah',
            lastReligion: 'Muslim',
        },      
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('An error occurred... Look at the console (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I, Console tab) for more information!');
            $('#resulte').html('<p>Status Code: '+jqXHR.status+'</p><p>ErrorThrown: ' + errorThrown + '</p><p>jqXHR.responseText:</p><div>'+jqXHR.responseText + '</div>');
            console.log('jqXHR:');
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log('textStatus:');
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log('errorThrown:');
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },

    });
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

in passwrapper.php

```
       <?php
include 'student.php';
executePass();

receivePost();
function receivePost()
{
    if ((!isset($_POST["lastName"])) and (!isset($_POST["lastReligion"])))
    {
        //do nothing
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo '<script>console.log("Last='.$_POST["lastName"].' lastReligion='.$_POST["lastReligion"].'");</script>';

    }
}

?>
```

in student.php

```
<?php
function executePass()
{

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','netwitness') or die ("Could not connect database");
    $db = mysqli_select_db($conn,'abdpractice') or die ('Could not select database');

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from student");
    $json_array = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $json_array[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($json_array);
}
?>
```

my question is how to show all data on the console log and also show the post data on the console.log.. please do not modify the student.php... only modify the passwrapper.php

Comment: don't return a script block from passwrapper.php. Return the _data_ (as JSON - right now you're not returning JSON, so there's probably an error if you look in the console), and then in your ajax "success" function you can do a console.log. Confusingly you also include the students.php in the same file. That _does_ return some JSON, but then the rest of passwrapper.php runs and tries to return some script. So the output to the browser will be a jumble of the two things, and be invalid.

Comment: can you elaborate more about ur sentence

Comment: which bit don't you understand? Check in your browser's network tab, at the ajax request - you'll see what the response coming back looks like. Firstly the output from executePass() and then the output from receivePost(). The second bit of output is not JSON and therefore invalid because you're telling the ajax call to expect json back.

Comment: i mean when i perform the ajax to the passwrapperphp and it will show all the data on the console.log. but for the ajax posted data, it is just a values and i want the passwrapper.ph to get the value and show those values on the console.log

Comment: the  first output is good as  it shows all the data but the the second output did not show at all..... in the network tab

Comment: PHP can't write to the console. `console.log(data);` in your ajax success is already logging the response, so there's no work to do there. What you do want to do is a) change receivePost() so it _returns_ (not echoes) an array (not `<script>` string) containing the POST variables. Then b) Change executePass() so it _returns_ (not echoes) $json_array (without doing json_encode). Then combine both arrays together. Then do json_encode on the resulting array and echo _that_. Then you'll get all your results returned together in one array, and your "success" function will take care of console.log

Comment: If that's not what you want, you'll have to explain more clearly. Perhaps you don't want the values from executePass at all, maybe? I don't know. P.S. "the second output did not show at all..... in the network tab"  I find this surprising, unless maybe your `If` statement within receivePost() did not work as expected? But if the values are sent properly, that should not be possible. You can do `var_dump($_POST);` at the start of your PHP to verify it. And/or check the request body in your network tab again.

Comment: Damn it... How about my method??? which is down below.. a) change receivePost() so it write the posted data to the file and dont change executepass()

Comment: Sorry, but you've never mentioned writing to a file before. There's no code that would save anything to a file. Where and what are you trying to save? And what is "my method"? I thought you wanted to return the data to the ajax response and log it on the console? I've just described a way to do that. But I'm not going to post an answer until I'm sure what you actually want, your explanation is not very clear unfortunately. Maybe give us an example of _exactly_ what you  want to see returned into the console?

Comment: let me explain more clearly.. In the ajax function, it will go to the passwrapper.php and this script include the file student.php to show all data in a json format on the html file console. then you can see all the data on the console.log. then i want to perform ajax post to post the values against the passwrapper.php and show those data on the console.log

Comment: please do not modify the student.php as i want to echo all the data.... only modify the passwrapper.php

Comment: so can you perhaps show me an example of the code for passwrapper.php ????

Comment: You can still echo both sets of data even if you modify students.php. It will be easier to combine the output into one array if we modify it so it returns the data to the caller instead of echoing it directly. Otherwise we'll have to output two separate bits of data in different echo commands, and it will be difficult to make that into one piece of valid JSON to send back to the browser. So to avoid that problem I will post a solution which modifies both.

Comment: If you're really not happy with that, I'll leave it to you to figure out how to do it with separate echo statements, you'd have to do some other string output in between which could be error prone, and at the very least will just be clumsy. That approach is not how most people would write their application.

Answer (score 0):

This should output the data from both functions combined, as JSON which your ajax "success" function can log. Your existing code has an issue because one part of it tries to return JSON, and the other part tries to return a `<script>` block, which is not valid JSON, and also would likely not be executed by the browser anyway for security reasons.

I've also modified the two functions so they return their output to the caller as PHP variables, rather than directly echo-ing JSON strings to the browser. This makes them more re-usable, and also makes it much simpler to then combine the results into a single coherent JSON object to output to the browser.

The `console.log(data);` command in your existing ajax "success" function will take care of logging all the returned data to your browser console.

```
$studentArr = executePass();
$postArr = receivePost();

echo json_encode(array("students" => $studentArr, "postvars" => $postArr));

function receivePost()
{
    if ((!isset($_POST["lastName"])) and (!isset($_POST["lastReligion"])))
    {
        //do nothing
    } 
    else 
    {
        return array ("lastName" => $_POST["lastName"], "lastReligion" => $_POST["lastReligion"]);
    }
}

function executePass()
{

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','netwitness') or die ("Could not connect database");
    $db = mysqli_select_db($conn,'abdpractice') or die ('Could not select database');

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from student");
    $json_array = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $json_array[] = $row;
    }


    return $json_array;
}
```

Now, I don't know the exact structure of your "students" data, so I can't give you an exact example of the output you'll receive, but if I were to assume that your students table had 3 simple fields - "id", "firstname", and "lastname", and there were 4 rows in the table, you would get a final JSON output something like this:

```
{
    "students":
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "firstname": "firstname1",
            "lastname": "lastname1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "firstname": "firstname2",
            "lastname": "lastname2"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "firstname": "firstname3",
            "lastname": "lastname3"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "firstname": "firstname4",
            "lastname": "lastname4"
        }
    ],
    "postvars": {
        "lastName": "Abdullah",
        "lastReligion": "Muslim"
    }
}
```

You have a JSON object with two properties. The "students" property contains an array of all the students in your table. The "postvars" property is another object containing properties matching the two POST variables you wanted to capture.

Comment: is it possible to combine the array of the whole data and the posted values if I change the return json _array to echo json_array???

Comment: not easily not because that the data is sent to the browser at that moment instead of returned to the calling code. As a general design rule, I try to make sure that functions themselves never echo content directly. It's more flexible if they just return data. Then the calling code at the actual endpoint can decide whether to process the data, to echo it, or in this case to combine it with other data. It's more flexible, and then you have re-usable data functions that you can call in different circumstances. I don't think you gain anything by echoing it directly...

Comment: ...but you do lose some flexibility over how you use your code. Also you'd need to do echo json_encode($json_array) if you were going to do that, because it isn't JSON yet. The problem you'll have is it will echo a single array, but then when you come to echo the POST data back, you have to output an object. Without combining them as I've done, you end up with an invalid JSON response to the client (one array + one object with no joining properties, commas etc). jQuery wouldn't be able to parse both bits of input into one `data` object.

Comment: You'd get `[{ "id" "student1"}, { "id": "student2" }]` from the first echo, and then `{ "lastName: "Abdullah", "lastReligion": "Muslim" }` from the  second echo. They still go into the same response to the browser, but together they're not a valid JSON object. You'd have to write all the surrounding bits (as per my example data) by hand as strings that you echo out, or something like that. So as I said earlier it would be very clumsy and error-prone, and you don't, as far as I can see, get any advantage from, only disadvantage. So can I ask - why are you keen to do it like that exactly?